# Can't update CMake

Tags: linux, cmake, opensuse

I tried to get the latest version of CMake, as OpenSUSE is stuck to 3.5.2.

```
version=3.10
build=2
mkdir ~/temp
cd ~/temp
wget https://cmake.org/files/v$version/cmake-$version.$build.tar.gz
tar -xzvf cmake-$version.$build.tar.gz
cd cmake-$version.$build/
./bootstrap
make -j3
sudo make install
```

But something went silently wrong:

```
VM-LINUX:~/temp/cmake-3.10.2 # cmake --version
CMake Error: Could not find CMAKE_ROOT !!!
CMake has most likely not been installed correctly.
Modules directory not found in
/usr/local/share/cmake
cmake version 3.5.2

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
```

So I tried another way: change the version in the update repositories! And then  I discovered that che CMake package is stuck at version 3.5.2 in OpenSUSE 42.3.

How can I add a repository so that I always have the latest version?

I'm a total newbie of Linux.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error regarding CMAKE_ROOT when installing CMake 3.12 from [Git](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake). The solution for me was to run:

`sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/cmake-3.12 /usr/local/share/cmake`

as it had installed in cmake-3.12 directory instead of cmake directory for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you were following ["How do I install the latest version of cmake from the command line?"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/355565/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-cmake-from-the-command-line).

I had the same problem and your problem/solution is to be found in the comments:

> When I ran this, I got an error CMake Error: Could not find `CMAKE_ROOT` !!! and it failed to update cmake. – Timothy Swan Dec 25 '17 at 21:47
>
> This is not a solution to `UPDATE` but to `INSTALL` cmake. Try this command or google it to find a solution: `sudo apt-get remove cmake cmake-data` - Teocci Dec 26 '17 at 2:18

Comment: I uninstalled CMake and then launched the commands in the question.
Now the situation has worsened:
 
    `$ cmake -version`   
    `bash: /usr/bin/cmake: is a directory`

I lost my CMake.

Furthermore:    
[1] should I need both the new and the old version, how should I get the old one back?    
[2] How to configure a repository in Package Manager that always keeps me updated?

Comment: @Ernesto_Che On Linux you don't need a `cmake` version installed to build `cmake` (see [here](https://cmake.org/install/): `If there is no existing CMake installation, a bootstrap script is provided`). Since you now have uninstalled your "old" version of `cmake`, first try to do `sudo make install` on the CMake source project again. If that's not working, remove/delete the `cmake-3.10.2` folder again and start with the steps again from scratch. Probably you also need to remove the half finished installation of the "new" version of `cmake` under `/usr/local/bin/cmake` first.

Comment: @Ernesto_Che And - if you always want to have the latest version of `cmake` - there is no Package Manager server that will automatically keep you up to the latest version. Some more possibilities and alternative servers are described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/829310/how-to-upgrade-cmake-in-ubuntu) or [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/610291/how-to-install-cmake-3-2-on-ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

```
Opensuse has provided Tumbleweed and Leap for us. Tumbleweed always includes the newest packages.
 Leap has the most stable version packages.
```

Regards